# Ajax not working after introducing jQuery toggleslide

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to Ajax and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I have a Wordpress theme which used Ajax to filter out search results. This was working fine until I introducted jQuery toggleslide to hide some of the categories in the search results (as there were 100's of categories).

In my html I have area that I click called "button" and this reveals the area called "results".

I've added this code to the header of my page and the toggleslide works great, but the problem is, when I click on one of the results to refine the search results the page reloads, as opposed to showing a "loading" sign.

If I delete the code then the "loading" sign works but the toggleslide

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").on("click",function(){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");
  });

});
</script>
```

I've looked into this and people suggest using the preventdefault() command so I tried this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").on("click",function(e){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");
  });

e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

Again the toggleslide works fine but the AJAX doesn't.

If anyone could help i'd really appreciate it.

Thanks
Chris

---------Update-----------

Thanks for the replies, unfortunately none of the below worked, i've also tried:

```
live("click",function())
click(function())
```

with no success.

I'll be able to paste other code tomorrow but i'm unsure this will be relevant? The reason been, if I remove the code above everything works as it should, therefore the above code is causing the issue? But I am new to this so appreciate you're help

Cheers
Chris

Comment: the e.preventDefault(); goes inside the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e.preventDefault()` should be inside of the `on("click", function(){})`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");
  });

});
```

I also noticed that you said:

> ...when I click on one of the results...

If you're making `#results` clickable as well, you'd need to do the same for it:

```
  $("#results").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do something
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the page still reloads?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide the rest of the pertinent HTML and JS? It'll help determine what's going on better

Comment: Hi Jonsuh.I've figured it out with the comments you provided. The problem was the logaction of the script src... Because I was entering this into a wordpress theme it wasn't inserting it into my header. I've hard coded this into my header.php and now it works fine. Thanks everyone for he help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").on("click",function(e){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Include e.preventDefault() inside button click event because scope of that is not available outside button click.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
$("#button").on("click",function(event){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

See , scope of EVENT is when its being clicked only .After that EVENT has No meaning